# Displaying the results of a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a javascript function to print out, but nothing comes up. Essentially I'm just setting up a basic page of text boxes, radio buttons and checkboxes for users to fill out and the results of those elements will print out to create a basic barebones profile page.

I apologize in advance for any sloppy or obsolete coding, I'm starting out with this stuff (my first semester of classes in web design). I'm assuming I've made a minor error that I'm not catching that's screwing up with the rest of the code, or I'm just plain missing a key line of code.

Here's the code below (Javascript):
`

```
function validate()
{
    dataOut = document.getElementById("profileOut");

    var color = document.profileIn.bgcolor.value;
    style.backgroundColor = color;

    var border = document.profileIn.border.value;
    style.border = border;

    var name = document.profileIn.name.value;
    dataOut.innerHTML = "<h1 id='name'>" name "</p>";

    if  (document.GetElementById('sportsgames').checked {
        dataOut.innerHTML = "<img src='images/sportsgames.jpg' alt='I like sports and games' />";
    } else if  (document.GetElementById('tvfilm').checked {
        dataOut.innerHTML = "<img src='images/tvfilm.jpg' alt='I like tv and film' />";
    } else if  (document.GetElementById('artlit').checked {
        dataOut.innerHTML = "<img src='images/artlit.jpg' alt='I like art and literature' />";
    } else {
        dataOut.innerHTML = "<img src='images/nothing.jpg' alt='I hate everything' />";
    }

    var entry1 = document.profileIn.entry1.value;
    dataOut.innerHTML = "<p id='para1'>" entry1 "</p>";
    document.getElementById("para1").style.color="#0000FF";
    var entry2 = document.profileIn.entry2.value;
    dataOut.innerHTML = "<p id='para2'>" entry2 "</p>";
    document.getElementById("para2").style.color="#FF0000";

    var years = document.profileIn.years.value;
    dataOut.innerHTML = "<p>I have been practicing this hobby for " + years + " years.</p>";

    var music = document.profileIn.music.value;
    dataOut.innerHTML = "<p> My favorite music genre is " + music + ".</p>";

    var birthday = document.profileIn.birthday.value;
    dataOut.innerHTML = "<p>Birthday:" + music + "</p>";

    var email = document.profileIn.email.value;
    dataOut.innerHTML = "<p> E-Mail:" + music + "</p>";

    var website = document.profileIn.website.value;
    dataOut.innerHTML = "<p>Website:" + music + "</p>";

    document.getElementById('profileOut').innerHTML = profileOut;
}

</script>`
```

And the HTML code as well:

```
<body id="profile">
<form id="profileIn" name="profileIn" method="post" onSubmit="return validate()">
    <fieldset id ="set1">
        <legend>Your Page</legend>
        <label for="bgcolor">
        <input type="color" id="bgcolor" name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" /> Select a background color<br>

        Choose the thickness of the border<br>
        <input type="range" id="border" name="border" value="5" min="0" max="10" step="1" /><br>
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="set2">
        <legend>Your Profile</legend>
        Enter your name <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /> <br>

        Enter your favourite hobby <br>
        <input type="radio" id="sportsgames" name="hobby" value="sportsgames">Sports & Games<br>
        <input type="radio" id="tvfilm" name="hobby" value="tvfilm">TV & Film<br>
        <input type="radio" id="artlit" name="hobby" value="artlit">Art & Literature<br><br>

        <label for="entry">What part of that hobby is your favourite?</label><br>
        <textarea id="entry1" name="comments1" rows="8" cols="50">Type in here...</textarea><br>    

        <label for="entry">Which part of that hobby are you best at?</label><br>
        <textarea id="entry2" name="comments2" rows="8" cols="50">Type in here...</textarea><br>

        How many years have you practiced this hobby? <br>
        <input id="years" type="number" name="years" value="0" min="1" max="100" /><br>

        What's your favorite genre of music? <br>
        <select id="music">
        <option value="Rock">Rock<option>
        <option value="Pop">Pop<option>
        <option value="Country">Country<option>
        <option value="R&B">R&amp;B<option>
        <option value="Classical">Classical<option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="set3">
        <legend>Your Info</legend>
        Birthday <input id="birthday" type="date" name="date" /> <br>
        Email <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" /> <br>
        Website <input id="website" name="website" type="url" placeholder="www.example.com" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="set4">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" id="btn1" value="Press to Continue" />
        <input class="btn" type="reset" id="btn2" value="Press to Clear" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

<section id="profileOut"> </section>
```

Any help's much appreciated, thanks guys!

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, be consistent when using `getElementById` (with lowercase `g`)

Comment: getElementById - you spelled that wrong. There is no capital G

Answer (score 0):

Lines like below are incorrect. In Javascript, appending should be done with `+`.

```
dataOut.innerHTML = "<h1 id='name'>" name "</p>";
```

should be

```
dataOut.innerHTML = "<h1 id='name'>" + name + "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

do you get any errors in your console? (F12 in the browser). Also, the return isn't necessary as far as I know:

```
onSubmit="return validate()">
```

can just be:

```
onSubmit="validate()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check your browser console for errors. A cursory glance revealed:

```
dataOut.innerHTML = "<p id='para1'>" entry1 "</p>";
```

Missing concatenation operators here.

In general, though, you seem to be repeatedly overwriting `dataOut.innerHTML`, which - assuming your code were correct - would just result in "Website: blah" and nothing else. Consider creating an element with `createElement`, adding text to it (`createTextNode`, `appendChild`) and then inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

First Error:

```
dataOut.innerHTML = "<h1 id='name'>"+name+"</p>"; //Missing +
```

Second to Forth

```
if  (document.GetElementById('sportsgames').checked) //Missing )
```

Fifth Error:

```
dataOut.innerHTML = "<p id='para1'>"+entry1+"</p>"; //Missing +
```

Sixth Error:

```
dataOut.innerHTML = "<p id='para2'>"+entry2+"</p>"; //Missing +
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to concatenate (`+`) some of your variables to your strings, like name, `entry1`, `entry2` so on

Always check your Developer Console if some of your JavaScript is not working.